# Identify a specific object from list of object and delete the selected item

Tags: android, object, shopping-cart

I'm trying to implement the delete option in the application cart. I have implemented a `ShoppingCartHelper` and it stores the item details.

This is how my product item object looks like in application cart.

[image]

I know I have to delete this object once the user is press the delete button. But I don't know how to delete the selected object from list of objects. Can anyone help me with the how can I access the specific item where user selected to delete from list of items. and once find the item object then how to delete the specific object.

This might be easy question for most of you but please don't underestimate me since this is my first android application.

**Shoppingcart.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

        mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, mCartList,
                getLayoutInflater(), true);

        expListView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    deleteCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
```

**ShoppingCartHelper.java**

```
public class ShoppingCartHelper {

    public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";
    private static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();

    public static void setQuantity(Product product, int quantity) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
        if (quantity <= 0) {
            if (curEntry != null)
                removeProduct(product);
            return;
        }

        // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
        if (curEntry == null) {
            curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity);
            cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
            return;
        }

        // Update the quantity
        curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public static int getProductQuantity(Product product) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        if (curEntry != null)
            return curEntry.getQuantity();

        return 0;
    }

    public static void removeProduct(Product product) {
        cartMap.remove(product);
    }

    public static List<Product> getCartList() {
        List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
        for (Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
            cartList.add(p);
        }

        return cartList;
    }

    public static ShoppingCartEntry getByProduct(Product product) {
        return cartMap.get(product);
    }
}
```

**ShoppingCartEntry.java**

```
public class ShoppingCartEntry {

    private Product mProduct;
    private int mQuantity;

    public ShoppingCartEntry(Product product, int quantity) {
        mProduct = product;
        mQuantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return mProduct;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return mQuantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        mQuantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

**ProductAdapter .java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<Product> mCartList;
    private Context _context;
    private List<Product> _cartList;
    private boolean mShowQuantity;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> cartList,
            LayoutInflater inflater, boolean showQuantity) {
        this._context = context;
        this._cartList = cartList;
        mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition)
                .hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView itemSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemSize);

        Item det = _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);

        itemSize.setText(det.itemName + " ( " + det.price + " ) ");

        mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int size = _cartList.get(groupPosition).getItems().size();
        System.out.println("Child for group [" + groupPosition + "] is ["
                + size + "]");
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._cartList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._cartList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_group, parent, false);
        }

        TextView groupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        TextView groupQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
        TextView groupSubtotal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotal);

        final Product cat = _cartList.get(groupPosition);

        groupName.setText(cat.description);
        groupQty.setText(String.valueOf(cat.quantity));
        groupSubtotal.setText(Double.toString(cat.subTotal));

        TextView editTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotccal);

        if (cat.itemCategory != null && cat.itemCategory.equals("Pizza"))
        editTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent next = new Intent(_context, ActivityPizzaEdit.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("subTotal", cat.subTotal);
                next.putExtras(b);
                next.putExtra("description", cat.description);

                _context.startActivity(next);
                ((Activity) _context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post some code about your implementation?

Comment: I have updated my question, can you take a look at it

Comment: Post product adapter code too